# Update connected service does not update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wsdl

I have a wsdl service linked to one of my apps, that I used to be able to update but for some reason I cannot anymore.
[image: image of the service]
I used to just click on the dots on the right of the service and select the correct settings and it would update. At the end, I get no message, the window just close as if it succeeded but nothing has changed.

I tried removing the link and recreating it at which point i get an error:

> Failed adding service reference(s). Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

I've looked up the issue and as far as I know, it should be resolved in the latest Visual studio version (for about a year now) so I updated and tried again to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that you are using a SDK project for net48 or some such, and this is one of the not supported scenarios.  I am currently running into the same problem and trying to determine if using the `wsdl.exe` from the command line is a suitable substitute.